Flutter showDatePicker Theme Colors Not Working as Expected
showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
  firstDate: DateTime.now(),
  lastDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 600)),
  builder: (BuildContext? context, Widget? child) {
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData().copyWith(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
          primary: Colors.green, // Header background color
          onPrimary: Colors.white, // Header text color
          surface: Colors.green, // Background color of selected date
          onSurface: Colors.black, // Text color of dates
        ),
        dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.white, // Dialog background color
      ),
      child: child ?? SizedBox.shrink(),
    );
  },
);

Actually, I just want to color the top part of the dialog. This is the scenario I encountered when I updated the code.

When I researched online, the code I looked at was the same, but I'm not getting the same result.
My Flutter version is Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.0, on macOS 14.6.1 23G93 darwin-arm64, locale tr-TR).

You should modify the datePickerTheme parameter instead of colorScheme and dialogBackgroundColor. In your example, the updated code would look like this:
showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
  firstDate: DateTime.now(),
  lastDate: DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 600)),
  builder: (BuildContext? context, Widget? child) {
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData().copyWith(
        datePickerTheme: DatePickerThemeData(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white, // Dialog background color
          headerBackgroundColor: Colors.green, // Header background color
          headerForegroundColor: Colors.white, // Header text color
          // Date text color
          dayForegroundColor: const WidgetStatePropertyAll(Colors.black),
          todayForegroundColor: const WidgetStatePropertyAll(Colors.black),
          // Selected date background color
          dayBackgroundColor: WidgetStateProperty.resolveWith(
            (states) => states.contains(WidgetState.selected)
                ? Colors.green
                : null,
          ),
          todayBackgroundColor: WidgetStateProperty.resolveWith(
            (states) => states.contains(WidgetState.selected)
                ? Colors.green
                : null,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: child ?? const SizedBox.shrink(),
    );
  },
);

Output:

